# Phpseclib hangs on read()

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I am trying to execute sudo command
using example from

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#sudo

But the script hangs after first read(). And after that I need to restart the whole server, apache continues working but not the php.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the example:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("sudo ls -la\n");
$output = $ssh->read('#[pP]assword[^:]*:|username@username:~\$#', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
echo $output;
if (preg_match('#[pP]assword[^:]*:#', $output)) {
    $ssh->write("password\n");
    echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
}
?>
```

`username@username:~$` is a placeholder for the prompt. Did you change it to whatever the prompt on your server is?

If you SSH in via PuTTY or OpenSSH or whatever you can see what the prompt is that way. Alternatively, you can do `$ssh->setTimeout(2)`. At that point `$ssh->read()` will return after two seconds with whatever the output it got back from the SSH server. The prompt - whatever it is - should be in that output.

Comment: if you think this is the answer please mark the answer :)